# How to Resize a vitual disk on an Ubuntu VM?

Tags: 20.04

```
sdc      8:32   0     7G  0 disk
sde      8:32   0     10G  0 disk
```

Hi, I have an ubuntu VM, I get remote access to it. When I run the lsblk command I'm showing the disks you see above, what I need to do is resize the **sdc** disk so the size is 5G instead of being 7G. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: yes in vbox settings